# Getting error while taking screenshots with Firebase in GCloud

Tags: android, firebase, android-espresso, gcloud

I am facing a lot of trouble trying to integrate screenshotter library from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/test-screenshots), into my very simple Android project. I followed the steps outlined in the tutorial pretty meticulously.

When I look at logs from gcloud I see the following error

> 01-07 19:41:06.724: E/cloud_screenshotter(5752): Exception taking
>   screenshot: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /sdcard/screenshots/com.computemachines.android.workplay.ClockingActivityScreenshotTest-takeScreenshot-main_screen_3-1.jpg:
>   open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Funnily enough, I have a different project in the same computer with almost identical build structure in which taking screenshots **work**! The gradle version, test case, build.gradle files are exactly the same in both.

An excerpt from [app/build.gradle](https://github.com/prolificcoder/android-notepad/blob/master/app/build.gradle) in the repo that doesn't work

```
androidTestCompile (name:'cloudtestingscreenshotter_lib', ext:'aar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // Espresso testing
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.google.code', module: 'jsr305'
}
```

The whole repo that doesn't work is at [GitHub](https://github.com/prolificcoder/work-play) and the repo that works is [here](https://github.com/prolificcoder/android-notepad).

The invocation command for invoking the builds and running on GCloud is the same for both

```
./gradlew clean assembleDebug assembleDebugAndroidTest && gcloud beta test android run \
  --type instrumentation \
  --app app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk \
  --test app/build/outputs/apk/*est-unaligned.apk \
  --device-ids Nexus6 \
  --os-version-ids 23 \
  --locales en \
  --orientations portrait
```

I have spent more than 10 hours on trying to figure this out and a summary mind map of all things I tried is [here](https://www.mindmeister.com/825796173/screenshot-not-working). I can provide any other information that is needed but wanted to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you use the same gcloud options for both projects, with the same device and os version?

Comment: Yup see above.. the gcloud command is exactly the same!

Comment: I have this issue also, so I'm interested if solution is found?

Answer (score 2):

In order to write the screenshot to the expected location, the app must hold the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, [as described in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/test-screenshots).

Comment: In the sample app yes I was missing the permission in the android manifest file. In my main project I had a seperate AndroidManfiest.xml with this permission in the androidTest folder but for it to merge correctly I also needed android:userid as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14196493/31252

Comment: I've never heard of userid ever being a problem for anyone before.